# dropdown list from google sheet script with option of inserting free text

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, bootstrap-4

So I'm trying to get a dropdown list that would allow me to also insert free text with this code I can select an item from my selected range in google sheet but is there a way to make it so it will also allow text input new text. Here's my code
I've also tried using Datalist (could be better) but I could not get it to work properly any help would be greatly appreciated

```
<div class="row">
        <script type="text/javascript"></script>
 
         <script>
          <?
          var sheet   = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID").getSheetByName("Sheet");
          var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();  
          var myRange = sheet.getRange("A2:A"+lastRow); 
          var data    = myRange.getValues();
          
          ?>
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(populategetEmp1).getEmp1();
         </script>  
   
    <div class="form col-md-6">
      <label for="emp1">Client</label>
        <select  id = "emp1" class="form-control" >
         <option value=""  ></option> 
         <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) { ?>
         <option ><?!= data[i] ?></option>
         <? } ?>
        </select>
      </div>
```

Comment: I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to add the text input for the dropdown list.

In this case, how about using the datalist tag as follows?

#### Modified script:

```
<script>
function test() {
  var value = document.getElementById("input").value;
  console.log(value)
}

//google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(populategetEmp1).getEmp1();
//
//function populategetEmp1() {
//  return;
//}
</script>

<div class="form col-md-6">
<label for="emp1">Client</label>
<input type="text" id="input" list="emp1" placeholder="Input text.">
<datalist id="emp1" class="form-control" >
  <?
  var sheet   = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID").getSheetByName("Sheet");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var myRange = sheet.getRange("A2:A"+lastRow);
  var data    = myRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) { ?>
  <option value="<?!= data[i] ?>">
  <? } ?>
</datalist>
</div>
<button onclick="test()">Click</button>
```

- When you open the HTML, you can input the free text to the text input.
- When you click the inverted triangle at the right side of the text input, the dropdown list is shown.
- When you click the button of "Click", the value is retrieve and you can see it at the console.

#### Reference:

- [datalist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist)

Comment: That works perfect thanks again for your help Tanaike